# how to get IP address and pc name of all pc's shared with me in a array using matlab script

Tags: matlab

the array should be looks like below.
      **PC NAME            IP ADDRESS**

```
    SYSTEM1           192.168.12.45
    SYSTEM2           192.168.12.4
    SYSTEM3           192.168.12.5
    SYSTEM4           192.168.12.15
```

Comment: how does the original string/text look like?

Comment: Which OS are we aiming at here? This is typically done with system commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run system commands from within Matlab.  So, on a Windows OS, you can run:

`[status,result] = system('arp -a')` to get a list of local IP addresses,

and then:

`[status,result] = system('nbtstat -a 192.168.1.163')` to get the names that correspond to each IP address... in this example, I was getting the name for 192.168.1.163 specifically.  Obviously you'll have to do some string manipulation from there.  Let me know if you need any help with that.